# How to print key value pair in Laravel using foreach loop

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreach, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I'm trying to send an array (containing data, i.e., first name, last name, URL, etc.) from the controller to the blade. Now I need to print it using foreach in the blade file. My question is, how can I print the individual values?

**Controller**

```
public function show_friend_request()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $get_friend_requests = DB::table('friendships')
        ->where('recipient_id', $user_id)->where('status',
        'pending')->get(['sender_id']);
    $array = json_decode($get_friend_requests, true);
    $count_friend_Request = count($array);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count_friend_Request; $i++) {
        $show_friend_request_Data[] = DB::table('users')
            ->leftJoin('friendships', 'friendships.sender_id', 
                '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('users.id', '=', $array[$i])
            ->get(['first_name', 'last_name']);
    }

    return view('pages.friend_request')->with('Active_Request', 
        $show_friend_request_Data);
}
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach($Active_Request as $friend => $value)
    <li>
        <div class="rounded badge-unread d-sm-flex border-0 mb-1 p-3 position-relative">
            <!-- Avatar -->
            <div class="avatar text-center">
                <img class="avatar-img rounded-circle" src="assets/images/avatar/01.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <!-- Info -->
            <div class="mx-sm-3 my-2 my-sm-0">
                <p class="small mb-2"><b>{{$friend}} : {{$value}}}</b> sent you a friend request.</p>
                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm py-1 btn-primary me-2">Accept</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm py-1 btn-danger-soft">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a mess. here is a cleaner version without using the models (since you did not say if they are in place)

**Controller Code**

```
public function show_friend_request()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    $senderIds = DB::table('friendships')->where('recipient_id', $user_id)->where('status', 'pending')->pluck('sender_id')->toArray();
    
    $activeRequests = DB::table('users')
        ->whereIn('id', $senderIds)
        ->get(['first_name','last_name']);

    return view('pages.friend_request')->with('activeRequest', $activeRequests);
}
```

**Blade Code**

```
@foreach($activeRequest as $key => $friend)
    <li>
        <div class="rounded badge-unread d-sm-flex border-0 mb-1 p-3 position-relative">
            <!-- Avatar -->
            <div class="avatar text-center">
                <img class="avatar-img rounded-circle" src="assets/images/avatar/01.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <!-- Info -->
            <div class="mx-sm-3 my-2 my-sm-0">
                <p class="small mb-2"><b>{{$key}} : {{$friend->first_name.' '.$friend->last_name}}</b> sent you a friend request.</p>
                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm py-1 btn-primary me-2">Accept </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm py-1 btn-danger-soft">Delete </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

The requests in the controller can be fused into one

```
public function show_friend_request()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    
    $activeRequests = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('friendships', 'friendships.sender_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('friendships.recipient_id', $user_id)
        ->where('friendships.status', 'pending')
        ->get(['first_name','last_name']);

    return view('pages.friend_request')->with('activeRequest', $activeRequests);
}
```

If you had the models and relations in place you can do

```
public function show_friend_request()
{
    $activeRequests = User::whereHas('friendships', function ($friendship) {
        $friendship->where('recipient_id', auth()->id())
            ->where('status', 'pending');
    })->get(['first_name','last_name']);

    return view('pages.friend_request')->with('activeRequest', $activeRequests);
}
```